# npm start gives me error 304 and 400 when launching angular 4 project

Tags: angularjs

systemjs.config.js

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: {
        app: "applicationStartup",
        '@angular/core': 'node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
    },
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: '../../build/main.js',
            defaultJSExtensions: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultJSExtensions: "js"
        }
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('applicationStartup').catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

My directory structure is as shown [image: here]

Now whwn I try to run my app with npm start i get the error as shown below:

```
304 GET /index.html
304 GET /node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js
304 GET /node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js
304 GET /systemjs.config.js
304 GET /node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
200 GET /build/main.js
304 GET /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
404 GET /build/app.module
```

Now , why it is not able to load the modules, is there anything wrong with the path?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 304 http is not an error. That means:

> HTTP Error 304 - Not modified 
>   This does not really indicate an error, but rather indicates that the resource for the requested URL has not changed since last accessed or cached.

So, it's appears just becouse you have no changes in that sources. 
Your problem is here:

> 404 GET /build/app.module

Check your path to app.module. Maybe it should has .js extension. It depends on current configuration.
Hope it will helpfull for you.

Comment: Yes, when build folder is generated it has `app.module.js` file generated. But how should I give path for it?

Comment: @MrugeshThaker try to edit your systemjs:
 where you have defaultJSExtensions: 'js
change it to: 
defaultExtension: 'js''

Comment: @MrugeshThaker defaultJSExtensions: true ?